# How to clear part of the console's display that's offscreen (scrolled away/up) in freepascal?

Tags: freepascal

I'm failing to find a way to really really clean everything off the screen, including the text that was pushed upwards due to lack of space, in console apps. I need this for nothing more than just aesthetic feel. Can it be done and how (cross-platform)? If it cant I must be misunderstanding how the console display works, could someone explain that too then?

Comment: Do you  need a cross-platform solution ? or only a MS Windows version?

Comment: Cross-platform unfortunately, I'm not even using it on Windows.

Comment: Ah, then I can't serve, sorry... For Windows you might use [the procedure](http://pastebin.com/MVFuHvYF) (without error handling), which I've just [translated](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261/en-us) or you could call `Exec('cmd.exe', '/C cls');`, but for other platforms I'm lost.

Comment: Still, thanks, I am going to keep the solution for windows, in case I would need it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

While using Unix (Linux) just send an "\033c" to the console, for example using write() and it'll do the magic ;)

Test it in pure shell using for example: printf "\033c"

Deeper explanation: "\033c" is the same as sending c to the console, which is VERY old (since VT100 terminal primitives!) command for clearing the whole screen and it's buffers.